# LiveStream My Desktop RTSP with FFMpegConverter.ConvertLiveMedia

Tags: c#, vb.net, ffmpeg

I'm putting together an application to stream from my desktop to an RTSP server. I used FFMPEG passing the following arguments:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -rtbufsize 100M -framerate 30 -probesize 10M -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://1.1.1.1:8554/player/1ef8d9a5-b0b3-4dab-93a0-ac2bdef2f8aa/index.m3u8
```

it worked perfectly, but I need to use FFMPEG within my application and not externally (via process). I looked and found a wrapper for .Net that apparently works very well, but I couldn't make it work with the arguments I used directly in FFMPEG.
The code I am using is the following:

```
 Dim outPath As String = "rtsp://1.1.1.1:8554/player/1ef8d9a5-b0b3-4dab-93a0-ac2bdef2f8aa"
 Dim inPath = "desktop"
 Dim videoConv = New FFMpegConverter()
 Dim ffMpegTask = videoConv.ConvertLiveMedia(inPath, Nothing, outPath, Format.flv, New ConvertSettings() With {
 .VideoFrameSize = "320x200",
 .CustomOutputArgs = "-f gdigrab -rtbufsize 100M -framerate 30 -probesize 10M -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://1.1.1.1:8554/player/1ef8d9a5-b0b3-4dab-93a0-ac2bdef2f8aa/index.m3u8",
 .VideoFrameRate = 30,
 .MaxDuration = 5
 })
 ffMpegTask.Start()
```

However, it doesn't work, it says that in Input, it must be a stream and that Desktop would not be valid.
Would anyone know how I can convert my argument line so that I can use it in the Video Converter for .NET FFMpeg C# wrapper????